# enable logging of password-like patterns in mysql client history

Tags: mysql

From MySQL 5.6.8 onwards, statements containing the pattern `*PASSWORD*` or `*IDENTIFIED*` are not logged in the `mysql` command line client history. I know I can add to this list with `--histignore` or `MYSQL_HIST_IGNORE`, but how do I defeat this filtering altogether? I'm working on a development server, never storing cleartext passwords and above all, *I did not ask for this behaviour*. It's my server, and I want to be able to cursor-up and get a previous query without cutting and pasting.

I posted a previous question on this topic when I couldn't work out why some queries were not being logged, but now we're on 5.6.22 and I'm wondering if anyone has found a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Working on a project with db columns like "password_hash", this behavior was at first very confusing and then over time, simply maddening.  There appears to be no way to disable this.

Here's an evil hack that I only resorted to out of desperation after other workarounds failed:

```
cp /usr/bin/mysql ~/bin     # copy to local bin dir
vim ~/bin/mysql             # vim can edit binary files
/PASSWORD                   # search for the offending string
RPWXUK4FD [ESC]             # overtype w/ string unlikely to ever match
:wq                         # save & quit
```

This assumes that you already have a ~/bin directory and it is listed before /usr/bin in your $PATH

Comment: Oh, great! Sadly that this is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-logging.html) you should use the [`--log-raw`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-raw) option in order for password rewriting in logs not to take place.

Comment: That's the query log, not the mysql client history. Adding `--log-raw` as a command line option does nothing. It's starting to look like this behaviour cannot be overridden, which is retarded.